# Skip empty lines for drawing a chart

Tags: excel, charts, line

I've got a table containing data and on the right are four columns aggregating a few of the lines resulting in new data. Having this the lines between aggregated data are empty and trying to chart that data results in gaps in the chart.

**I want to chart only the aggregated data not the (empty) lines between.** At the moment I've tried using #NA or NA() and properties in the select-data-dialog but nothing works. The only thing would be to deselect every empty line in the select-data-prop-window but there's of data and this would be too much work everytime new data comes.

[image]

Comment: Just make a helper table then that doesnt include the lines without values

Comment: that would be with VBA, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple approach is to use a PivotChart:

[image: Img]

1. Select the data and Insert a PivotTable
2. Add Label and Data elements to the PivotTable
3. Summarize Data by Sum
4. Hide the Row Label that is blank or has #NV to exclude the rows without data
5. Select the PivotTable then go to the PivotTable Tools > Analyze tab
6. Click the PivotChart button then select chart type

Comment: That could work according to your image! The rows with NA need to be shown because they all contain data except in these columns (which aggregate data from multiple lines). So that version here seems to be fitting. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple but temporary solution, is to use an autofilter to hide the blank rows:

From:

[image: From]

To:

[image: To]